# Initialrotationpreference does not apply to splash screen properly in windows 8.1 WinRT APP

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In the Package.appxmanifest of a windows 8.1 winrt project, if you set the initial rotation preference as portrait

```
<m2:VisualElements DisplayName="SplashScreen" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Square30x30Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="SplashScreen" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646">
  <m2:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
    <m2:InitialRotationPreference>
       <m2:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
    </m2:InitialRotationPreference>
</m2:VisualElements>
```

If the windows 8 / windows 8.1 / windows 10 tablet is held in landscape, the splash screen first shows up in landscape mode and then rotates to portrait mode, however the same issue is not observed for windows universal apps.

Is there a way to get the splash screen as portrait? 
Has somebody faced this issue?

Comment: I have uploaded the sample code at https://onedrive.live.com/?id=2F14B4EE5F346B6F%21105&cid=2F14B4EE5F346B6F&group=0

Comment: Try to shorten your code into something that can reproduce your issue and is short enough to include in the question.